# MyBatis mapper exception not caught when running multiple statements in one insert tag

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I am using MyBatis to execute some set of queries on database. My insert tag looks like below.

```
<insert id="dosomething">
   insert statement....;
   insert statement...
   update statement.....;
   update statement...
</insert>
```

This method is being invoked by Spring task which is defined in Spring file to run in interval of 10 seconds.

Weird thing what happening is that whenever this is some exception due to data base in update statement. I don't get this exception caught at java code from where this is called. And task stops running from that point and never come back.

Is it because of me trying the update statement in insert tag?
Will this be causing task to stop for ever?

Comment: Did you try to catch "Exception" instead of something like "MapperException"? Because often the real exception you are looking for is inner exception of thrown one.

Comment: Please add a code snippet that gives us an impression about what your actual context is and that makes your problem reproducible, including the information where you encounter your specific problem.

Comment: This is sample code :- \n
 <insert id="doSomething">
        insert into table1   select * from table1 where id ='114' ;

        
        insert into table2(ID)
        SELECT
        ID
        FROM
        table1
        WHERE
        id= '114';

  UPDATE table1 o
  set  id=115        
  from
  table2 t
 where
   t.id=o.id ;
</insert>

On Netezaa, In the update statement it is giving exception :-
Update canceled: attempt to update target row with values from multiple join rows

Mapper Def:-
public interface TestMapper {
     void doSomething();

}